# ggplot - get date label in Mon-yyyy format

Tags: r, ggplot2

With a dataframe like below

```
data = data.frame(
  name=rep(c('Toyota', "Honda", "Nissan") ,each=4)
  ,date=c(rep(seq(as.Date("2016/1/1"), by = "month", length.out = 4),2),rep(seq(as.Date("2017/1/1"), by = "month", length.out = 4),1)),
  sales=sample(10:20, 12, replace=T)
  )
```

I want to plot a line graph of sales as below;

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data, aes(x=date, y=sales)) + geom_line(aes(color=name))
```

This gives me the x-axis labels as `2016-01` ... `2017-01` and so on.

[image: Plot]

I need to get the x-axis labels as `Jan-2016`, `Feb-2016` and so on.

Comment: Try add something like `+ scale_x_date(date_breaks = "1 month", date_labels = "%b-%Y")`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

@Z.Lin's comment suggesting using  `+ scale_x_date(date_breaks = "1 month", date_labels = "%b-%Y")` answers your requirement perfectly. You appear to have a large unplotted gap in the dates you are interested in, at least in your sample data, which makes the axis labels too crowded as individual months in their current form. A minor variation on @Z.Lin's solution changing the breaks to every two months and using a line break in the date format in place of the dash separator helps readability a little:

```
ggplot(data, aes(x=date, y=sales)) + 
  geom_line(aes(color=name))+
  scale_x_date(date_breaks = "2 month", date_labels = "%b\n%Y")+
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(size = 8))
```

[image]